# How to get access to Arguments/Extras Bundle in ViewModel with minimal boilerplate using Dagger 2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I'm transitioning my app to use `ViewModel`s. For instantiating the `ViewModel`s I use a custom `Factory` and Dagger 2 for dependency injection. It looks like this:

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val viewModels: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T 
        = viewModels[modelClass]!!.get() as T
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION) @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME) @MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)

@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds @IntoMap @ViewModelKey(FooViewModel::class)
    abstract fun fooViewModel(viewModel: FooViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

Now I'm facing the question, how to access the Arguments/Extras `Bundle` of my `Fragment` or `Activity` inside a `ViewModel`. This is necessary because the views and therefore the data in the `ViewModel` is often parametrizable. How would I implement this using the least amount of boilerplate?

Comment: I think you should create a method like ViewModel.setArguments(bundle: Bundle) etc. This is clearer solution.

Answer (score 6):

If you use [Saved State](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) module, both activity intent extras and fragment arguments are available via [SavedStateHandle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle)

```kotlin
class SavedStateViewModel(private val state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
  init {
    val someArgument = state.get<String>("someArgumentKey")
    ...
  }
}
```

You can also use [AssistedInject](https://github.com/square/AssistedInject) library to pass arguments from an Activity/Fragment into a ViewModel, but it's a boilerplate solution. Here's a [dagger example](https://coroutinedispatcher.com/posts/how-to-produce-savedstatehandle-in-your/), and [another one](https://gist.github.com/manuelvicnt/437668cda3a891d347e134b1de29aee1) which uses [dagger hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/).

Answer (score 2):

What about injecting such extras/arguments into your viewmodels? You may achieve this by accessing such activity/fragment with dagger.

```
@Module
class IntentModule {
    @Provides
    fun retriveIntentWithExtraX(activity: DestinationActivity): Long {
        return activity.intent.getSerializableExtra(SOME_EXTRA_DATA) as Long
    }
}
```

And inside module with your activies/fragments:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModules {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [IntentModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeDestinationActivity(): DestinationActivity

}
```

finally you can inject such arguments/extra into your ViewModels like that:

```
class SomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val someExtraData: Long
) : ViewModel()
```

Comment: Will this work with Hilt when annotating the Activity or Fragmemt with @AndroidEntryPoint? I mean, will it be available in the Intent Module?